# Assign VMware Public IP's

Tags: virtual-machine, esxi

Let me rephrase a previous question.

I have 10 virtual machines running on a ESXI server

How do i assign them a different public IP to the host and each other? And do i need any exceptions in any on my Cisco ASA firewalls?

Comment: Does this relate to port-forwarding and/or DNS?

Comment: I don't know, i just want know how to assign a static ip to a vmware vm

Comment: You assign a static ip to a VM exactly as you do to a physical computer, while the computer is booted up. Is that the question?

Comment: But do i need to configure NAT on that computer and give it a internal address within its public network?

Comment: What do you mean by public IP? If the VMs are open to the internet, they all share externally the same IP. You may do port-forwarding, but this means using different port numbers per each VM.

Comment: No, they need to have a public address each... that what i'm trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have the router receive 10 public IP addresses and remap them to
10 internal IP addresses.

You will need some virtual machine that will server as a WAN gateway
(or as virtual router) to act as gateway for the 10 virtual machines that will
serve each address.

In this case the gateway VM will have two network interfaces, one is connected to
the router and a second one for the LAN. You can configure NAT services on
the gateway VM to allow you to connect to the internal management of ESXi
as well as to the 10 server VMs.

The network will look like this:

[image]